# Using SQL reserved words in Hive when creating external temporary table

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hive-table

I need to create an external hive table from hdfs location where one column in files has reserved name (end).

When running the script I get the error:
"cannot recognize input near 'end' 'STRUCT' '<' in column specification"

I found 2 solutions.

The first one is to set hive.support.sql11.reserved.keywords=false, but this option has been removed.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-14872

The second solution is to use quoted identifiers (`column`).

But in this case I get the error: 
"org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('c' (code 99)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries"

This is my code for table creation:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY EXTERNAL TABLE ${tmp_db}.${tmp_table}
(
    id STRING,
    email STRUCT<string:STRING>,
    start STRUCT<long:BIGINT>,
    end STRUCT<long:BIGINT>
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION '${input_dir}';
```

It's not possible to rename the column.

Does anybody know the solution for this problem? Or maybe any ideas?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

can you try below.

```
hive> set hive.support.quoted.identifiers=column;
hive> create temporary table sp_char ( `#` int, `end` string);
```

OK
Time taken: 0.123 seconds

```
OK
Time taken: 0.362 seconds
hive>
```

When you set hive property `hive.support.quoted.identifiers=column` all the values within back ticks are treated as literals.
Other value for above property is **none** , when it is set to none you can use regex to evaluate the column or expression value.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot for advise! But unfortunately I still get the error: "org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('e' (code 101)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')"

Comment: This error might be for a different issue.. can you give the sample json data for the table which u trying to create

Comment: Here's an example: {"id_1":875e56a,"id_2":null,"email":null,"id_3":null,"category":{"int":3},"id_4":null,"start":{"long":1541835670},"end":{"long":1544663240}}.    The problem might be in the first field (id_1) because the letter shown in exception is the one of the letters in id_1 value (not always the first letter met) in some cases (The error message is: Unexpected character ('a' (code 97)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries". But sometimes there's  a message: "Unrecognized token 'f9809': was expecting 'null', 'true' or 'false'" for the value "id_1":f9a84049 for example.

Comment: Sorry, Am having issue in creating table with JSON serde itself, Cannot help further on this

Comment: Thanks for trying to help!